# WordPress style doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, styles

I was trying to include a styles file in WordPress plugin. This styles need to be work on front end. But below codes doesn't work.

```
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_register_style( 'buttons', plugins_url( 'includes/parts/css/buttons.css' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'buttons' );
    }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

What is the issue here? I have tried all other stackoverflaw ansers too. When I add styles directly to theme style.css file it works

Comment: You are using `wp_enqueue_scripts` **instead of ** `wp_enqueue_style` for style.Try again by changing that.

Comment: Then put edited code ..Why these code ?

Comment: This code is taken from official WordPress site

Comment: Can you give me the link please ?

Comment: You're using `plugins_url` wrong.

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner, using the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook is the correct way of doing it. There is no `wp_enqueue_styles` hook.

Comment: @rnevius Sorry!!Completely mistaken question in rush ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a second argument [plugins_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) is giving you the path to the `/plugins` directory, not the directory of YOUR plugin. Assuming the above is coming from a file in the root of your plugin, you could do the following:

```
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_register_style( 'buttons-style', plugins_url( 'includes/parts/css/buttons.css', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'buttons-style' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

Comment: That's not a problem with the code above. Rather, you have a syntax error somewhere else.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting '`' in

Comment: ...in? What's the rest of it? You should have a line number, and you should be able to see what comes before it.

Comment: Really sorry. It was an unexpected character. btw, this code doesn't work :(. Any idea why?

Comment: Actually will this code load this stylesheet on front end?

Comment: Avoid name "button" and use some other names. Not file name, the name which you use for registering your style. Use this code by @rnevius and change name from "buttons" to something like "buttons-styles"

Comment: Oh man !!!! That works !! I can't believe that it was because of just one name.. Thanks a lot @JoelSays and rnevius